# Код работает при втором клике

Tags: javascript

У меня есть вот такой код на сайте, но почему то он раз через раз работает только при втром клике

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //adding to favorite
    $('body').on('click', '.add-favorite', function() {
        var post_id = $(this).data('post_id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'favorite',
                'post_id': post_id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.fv_' + post_id).html('<a href="https://askam.pro/favorite/"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                $('.num-favorite').html(data);
            },
        });
    });

    //deleting from favorite
    $('body').on('click', '.delete-favorite', function() {
        var post_id = $(this).data('post_id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'delfavorite',
                'post_id': post_id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.fv_' + post_id).html('Deleted');
                $('.num-favorite').html(data);
            },
        });
        window.location.replace("https://askam.pro/favorite");
    });
});
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что такое нужно отлаживать на самом ресурсе.. так по коду.. ничего подозрительного

Comment: ну навскидку, возможно `window.location.replace` релоадит страницу раньше, чем отрабатывает асинхронный `$.ajax` и вы продолжаете видеть что-то в фаворитах. Со второго клика страница релоадится, но ajax уже отработал и фаворит исчез